# Bluetooth module doesn't receive

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

For a college project of mine, I am using an Arduino Duemilanove micro-controller to connect a bluetooth module to my Android Device Sony Xperia Tipo Dual using the app called BlueTerm. I have two bluetooth modules [1.Bluetooth Module UART, Model: RKI-1546](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=354) and [2.Model: RKI-1545](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=354).

But the problem I have is that, After I connect the micro-controller's RX to module's TX and vice versa, and send a character from my app, there is no change in the serial monitor(in the Arduino Software). I mean it doesn't display any character i had sent. However it works just fine the other way round. That is, when I type something on my serial monitor and press send, it readily appears on the mobile. I have tried 3 different RKI-1546's and a RKI-1545. I have tried using Arduino Mega(in place of Arduino Duemilanove) too. But this problem persists. The bluetooth module doesn't seem to recieve anything.
I hope if you can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can send data to your phone, you have set your baud rate correctly, and the pins wired correctly. Without your code I/we can't help you, so please post your code.

Thom

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. There was a problem with the bluetooth module. The RX pin was actually the TX pin and vice versa. Manufacturer's fault. Fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hardware fault not software. Total error in Arduino Due.

Fix this bug:

[image: bug in Arduino Due]